# Angular select of dynamic values show only a specific count of values in dropdown - bootstrap 5

Tags: angular, select, dynamic, dropdown, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am having a service from my backend that returns a list of all countries.
In my component i loop through the array and want the user to select one of the countries.

I am using bootstrap 5

```
<select class="form-select" formControlName="country">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value="country.code">
    {{(country.code) ? country.code : "XX"}} - {{(country.name) ? country.name : "XX"}}
  </option>
</select>
```

My problem is that when i open the dropdown over 20 countries are showing and it doesnt look fine. Is it possible to set a limit in this dropdown ? To show for example only 5 ? The user can still type in the field to find what he wants or scroll

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it fits for you to use "size" attribute on

Comment: i tried that, this doesnt work